# Viewing a hidden powershell script

Tags: shell, powershell, batch-file

I have 2 scripts, one is a .bat file and the other a .ps1 file

Runshell.ps1

```
while($true)  
{  
python discobot.pyw  
}  
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Start.bat
`powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -file %cd%\RunShell.ps1`

Is there a way to retrieve and view that hidden powershell process?

Comment: So you have a batch file that runs a powershell script that runs a python script?? Is there a reason you wouldn't do this loop and prompt in your pythin script, then just simply launch that directly?

Comment: @briantist I've been meaning to do that, this is just for later purposes